# Has the Thermal Imploder ever been used in Star Wars canon?

Tags: star-wars, weapon, star-wars-battlefront

In DICE's 2015 *Battlefront*, one of my favorite pickups was the thermal imploder. The look and sound was so satisfying. I was curious, has it ever been used or mentioned in Star Wars canon? I think technically Battlefront is canon as it was released in the Disney era but has it been used in any other media?

I saw someone claim it was used in *Rogue One* to destroy the ship Bodhi was on, but the look and sound wasn't right.

[image: Thermal Imploder in use in Battlefront 2015]

Note: Slave I's seismic charges have a similar sound but are very different weapons.

Comment: Not in canon, as far as I can tell; https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Thermal_imploder

Comment: Yeah I checked wookiepedia first. My thought was maybe it had a minor appearance in a book or comic that didn't get listed there.

Comment: As far as I can tell, whoever edited that Wookieepedia article is conflating multiple pieces of low canon (video game) evidence without justification. They aren't called Thermal imploders in any of the Rogue One properties (film, novelisation, visual dictionary, etc)

Comment: According to the often wrong ChatGPT it thinks it appears in the novel  "Star Wars: Aftermath" by Chuck Wendig. However you'll need someone with (a searchable) copy of this book to check if the old chatdroid is correct on this occasion...

Comment: @WiggotheWookie - It does not. I've checked every canon novel, junior novel and film novelisation for the term 'imploder'. It's not to be found

Comment: @Valorum chatgpt wrong? I'm shocked! Shocked I tells you.

Comment: @WiggotheWookie - Plenty of thermal detonators, no thermal imploders in Aftermath.